# Property 'EmployeeID' not found on type bean.Employee

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

I'm trying to display all list of the employees in a table and also delete it at the same table. But this error keep bothering me. What could be its reason?

```
May 28, 2017 9:25:27 PM 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'EmployeeID' not found on type bean.Employee

May 28, 2017 9:25:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DisplayAllEmp] in context with path [/ELMS] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /elms/elms_skms/DeleteEmployeeAcc.jsp at line 55

52:                                     <tbody>
53:                                         <c:forEach items="${employee}" var="emp">
54:                                             <tr>
55:                                                 <td><c:out value="${emp.EmployeeID}" /></td>
56:                                                 <td><c:out value="${emp.EmployeeIC}" /></td>
57:                                                 <td><c:out value="${emp.EmployeeName}" /></td>
58:                                                 <td><c:out value="${emp.EmployeePosition}" /></td>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'EmployeeID' not found on type bean.Employee
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:266)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:243)
```

Here is my jsp page:

```
<div class="module-body table">
<form name = delete" method="POST" action="DeleteEmployeeServlet">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="datatable-1 table 
table-bordered table-striped     display" width="50%">

<thead>
<tr>
<th>Employee ID</th>
<th>Employee IC</th>
<th>Employee Name</th>
<th>Employee Position</th>
<th>Employee Session</th>
<th>Employee Grade</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<c:forEach items="${employee}" var="emp">
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${emp.EmployeeID}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${emp.EmployeeIC}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${emp.EmployeeName}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${emp.EmployeePosition}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${emp.EmployeeSession}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${emp.EmployeeGrade}" /></td>
<td><a href="DeleteEmployeeServlet?table=employee&employeeid=<c:out 
     value="${emp.EmployeeID}" />"onclick="return confirm('Are you 
     sure?');"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a> <br></td>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

Here is my servlet page:

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import model.EmployeeDAO;
import bean.Employee;

public class DeleteEmployeeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private EmployeeDAO dao;

    public DeleteEmployeeServlet() {
        super();
        dao = new EmployeeDAO();
    }  
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String forward = "";
        String table = request.getParameter("table");
        if(table.equalsIgnoreCase("employee")){
            int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("EmployeeID"));
            dao.DeleteEmployeeDetails(id);
            forward = "DisplayAllEmp?table=employee";
        }
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
        view.forward(request, response);
    }

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {}

}
```

Here is my model/DAO (viewEmployee):

```
public List<Employee> viewEmployee() {
        List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        try {
            currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            stmt = currentCon.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from employee");
            while (rs.next()) {
                Employee e = new Employee();
                e.setEmployeeID(rs.getInt("EmployeeID"));
                e.setEmployeePassword(rs.getString("EmployeePassword"));
                e.setEmployeeName(rs.getString("EmployeeName"));
                e.setEmployeeIC(rs.getString("EmployeeIC"));
                e.setEmployeeGender(rs.getString("EmployeeGender"));
                e.setEmployeeEmail(rs.getString("EmployeeEmail"));
                e.setEmployeePhoneNo(rs.getString("EmployeePhoneNo"));
                e.setEmployeeStreet1(rs.getString("EmployeeStreet1"));
                e.setEmployeeStreet2(rs.getString("EmployeeStreet2"));
                e.setEmployeePCode(rs.getInt("EmployeePCode"));
                e.setEmployeeCity(rs.getString("EmployeeCity"));
                e.setEmployeeState(rs.getString("EmployeeState"));
                e.setEmployeeQualification(rs.getString("EmployeeQualification"));
                e.setEmployeePosition(rs.getString("EmployeePosition"));
                e.setEmployeeSession(rs.getString("EmployeeSession"));
                e.setEmployeeGrade(rs.getInt("EmployeeGrade"));
                e.setEmploymentDate(rs.getDate("EmploymentDate"));
                employee.add(e);
                System.out.println("Employee id: " + e.getEmployeeID());
            }
            System.out.println("All rows from table view Employee retrieved!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed: An SQL Exception occured : " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return employee;
    }
```

Here is my DAO for DisplayAllEmp:

```
public void DeleteEmployeeDetails(int id) {
        try {
            currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            ps = currentCon.prepareStatement("delete from employee where employeeID=?");
            // Parameters start with 1
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("1 row of table Employee has been deleted. employeeID:" + id);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is my bean (Employee):

```
package bean;

import java.util.Date;

public class Employee {

    private int EmployeeID;
    private String EmployeePassword;
    private String EmployeeName;
    private String EmployeeIC;
    private String EmployeeGender;
    private String EmployeeEmail;
    private String EmployeePhoneNo;
    private String EmployeeStreet1;
    private String EmployeeStreet2;
    private int EmployeePCode;
    private String EmployeeCity; 
    private String EmployeeState;
    private String EmployeeQualification;
    private String EmployeePosition;
    private String EmployeeSession;
    private int EmployeeGrade;
    private Date EmploymentDate;
    private boolean valid;

    public Employee() {
        EmployeeID = 0;
        EmployeePassword = null;
        EmployeeName=null;
        EmployeeIC=null;
        EmployeeGender=null;
        EmployeeEmail=null;
        EmployeePhoneNo=null;
        EmployeeStreet1=null;
        EmployeeStreet2=null;
        EmployeePCode=0;
        EmployeeCity=null; 
        EmployeeState=null;
        EmployeeQualification=null;
        EmployeePosition=null;
        EmployeeSession=null;
        EmployeeGrade=0;
        EmploymentDate=null;
    }

    public Employee(int employeeID, String employeePassword, String employeeName, String employeeIC, String employeeGender, String employeeEmail, String employeePhone, String employeeStreet1, String employeeStreet2, int employeePCode, String employeeCity, String employeeState, String employeeQuaification, String employeePosition, String employeeSession, int employeeGrade, Date employmentDate) {
        EmployeeID = employeeID;
        EmployeePassword = employeePassword;
        EmployeeName=employeeName;
        EmployeeIC=employeeIC;
        EmployeeGender=employeeGender;
        EmployeeEmail=employeeEmail;
        EmployeePhoneNo=employeePhone;
        EmployeeStreet1=employeeStreet1;
        EmployeeStreet2=employeeStreet2;
        EmployeePCode=employeePCode;
        EmployeeCity=employeeCity; 
        EmployeeState=employeeState;
        EmployeeQualification=employeeQuaification;
        EmployeePosition=employeePosition;
        EmployeeSession=employeeSession;
        EmployeeGrade=employeeGrade;
        EmploymentDate=employmentDate;
    }

    public int getEmployeeID() {return EmployeeID;}
    public void setEmployeeID(int employeeID) {EmployeeID = employeeID;}

    public String getEmployeePassword() {return EmployeePassword;}
    public void setEmployeePassword(String employeePassword) {EmployeePassword = employeePassword;}

    public String getEmployeeName() {return EmployeeName;}
    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {EmployeeName = employeeName;}

    public String getEmployeeIC() {return EmployeeIC;}
    public void setEmployeeIC(String employeeIC) {EmployeeIC = employeeIC;}

    public String getEmployeeGender() {return EmployeeGender;}
    public void setEmployeeGender(String employeeGender) {EmployeeGender = employeeGender;}

    public String getEmployeeEmail() {return EmployeeEmail;}
    public void setEmployeeEmail(String employeeEmail) {EmployeeEmail = employeeEmail;}

    public String getEmployeePhoneNo() {return EmployeePhoneNo;}
    public void setEmployeePhoneNo(String employeePhoneNo) {EmployeePhoneNo = employeePhoneNo;}

    public String getEmployeeStreet1() {return EmployeeStreet1;}
    public void setEmployeeStreet1(String employeeStreet1) {EmployeeStreet1 = employeeStreet1;}

    public String getEmployeeStreet2() {return EmployeeStreet2;}
    public void setEmployeeStreet2(String employeeStreet2) {EmployeeStreet2 = employeeStreet2;}

    public int getEmployeePCode() {return EmployeePCode;}
    public void setEmployeePCode(int employeePCode) {EmployeePCode = employeePCode;}

    public String getEmployeeCity() {return EmployeeCity;}
    public void setEmployeeCity(String employeeCity) {EmployeeCity = employeeCity;}

    public String getEmployeeState() {return EmployeeState;}
    public void setEmployeeState(String employeeState) {EmployeeState = employeeState;}

    public String getEmployeeQualification() {return EmployeeQualification;}
    public void setEmployeeQualification(String employeeQualification) {EmployeeQualification = employeeQualification;}

    public String getEmployeePosition() {return EmployeePosition;}
    public void setEmployeePosition(String employeePosition) {EmployeePosition = employeePosition;}

    public String getEmployeeSession() {return EmployeeSession;}
    public void setEmployeeSession(String employeeSession) {EmployeeSession = employeeSession;}

    public int getEmployeeGrade() {return EmployeeGrade;}
    public void setEmployeeGrade(int employeeGrade) {EmployeeGrade = employeeGrade;}

    public Date getEmploymentDate() {return EmploymentDate;}
    public void setEmploymentDate(Date employmentDate) {EmploymentDate = employmentDate;}

    public boolean isValid() {return valid;}
    public void setValid(boolean valid) {this.valid = valid;}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, you might need to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please also provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to increase the likelihood of getting your question answered instead of so many code lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Employee` class has private fields only, hence you cannot access them using dot notation. The `setters` and `getters` are public and accessible outside of the class. Use them to retrieve the information you want in your `jsp` file.

Furthermore, take a look on the Oracle's documentation page [Declaring Member Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html), section `Access Modifiers`.

> - public modifier—the field is accessible from all classes.
> - private modifier—the field is accessible only within its own class.

When you write `${emp.EmployeeID}`, you are asking for a field named `EmployeeID` which has `public` access modifier, which does not exist.

Comment: I've been tried to public all the private attributes. But the output still not as expected. Do u have any other solution for this error ?

Comment: @AinOmar you do not need to change the fields to public, you just have to use the `getters`. What was the error when you changed the access modifiers?